# Mutually-dependent C++ classes, held by std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

I was curious if was possible to create two classes, each of which holds a `std::vector` of the other.  My first guess was that it would not be possible, because `std::vector` requires a complete type, not just a forward declaration.

```
#include <vector>

class B;
class A { std::vector<B> b; };
class B { std::vector<A> a; };
```

I would think that the declaration of `std::vector<B>` would cause an immediate failure, because `B` has an incomplete type at this point.  However, this compiles successfully under both gcc and clang, without any warnings.  Why doesn't this cause an error?

Comment: So why `class B; class A {std::vector<B> b; }; A a; class B{std::vector<A> a; }` works ? At the time A is instanciated, B is not complete.

Comment: This will be particularily interesting if you define B later with a few deleted member functions which a vector needs, i.e. assignment and copy ctor.

Comment: This is UB before C++17 (because instantiating standard library templates with incomplete types causes undefined behavior unless otherwise specified), well-defined after [N4510](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html).

Comment: @T.C. Could you make this an answer? I feel like this should be a lot more prominent than a comment.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Note it doesn't answer the question, which is about the mechanics. Standard containers invoking UB here isn't a syntax issue, it's a library issue (which, due to the same mechanics, surprised some of the library implementors). But it's not what OP is asking about. Nonetheless, interesting. See [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

T.C commented that this is actually undefined behavior which is being addressed in a change request to the standard. The rule which is violated is apparently [res.on.functions] 2.5:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: [...]
>
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

The reason this works anyway (and the reason that it can be standardized) is two-fold:

1. Your program only contains type definitions; no objects are created, no functions are called, no code is generated. If we simplify it by eliminating B's definition (it's not needed) and then try to create an instance of `A`, it fails:

   ```
   class B;
   class A { std::vector<B> b; };
   A a; // error: ctor and dtor undefined for incomplete type B.
   ```

   What also fails, as expected, is a simple

   ```
   std::vector<B> b;
   ```

   The reason in both cases is that the compiler must produce code, as opposed to a mere type declaration which is only grammatically relevant.

   The use of the vector *type* is ok also in other contexts:

   ```
   typedef std::vector<B> BVec;
   ```
2. Class `A` can be defined because, as Nikolay correctly says in his answer, the size of `std::vector<B>`, and hence the size of `A`'s member `b`, does not depend on the definition of `B` (because a vector holds a pointer to an array of elements, not an array proper).

Comment: I don't see a compiler error with gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59493548b1702e6d Class definitions are exactly as OP wrote them.

Comment: @AndyG Note he removed B's declaration. So it remained just a forward reference at the point of generating code for A.

Comment: @AndyG I omitted the full definition of B in order to show what you can and cannot do with an incomplete type. After the full definition (as in your example) you are of course free to do anything you like. (Ah, thx, Yam.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Maybe I missed something, but wouldn't [this](http://rextester.com/ZTF14710) have to work, by the same logic?

Comment: @YamMarcovic You have a point. The compiler must know the size of the data members, I think, as Nikolay said before.

Answer (score 4):

This compiles and runs ok because `std::vector` uses pointers and not the exact definition of `A` or `B`. You could modify your example to use single instance or array in the definition of the classes like so

```
class B;
class A { public: B b[2]; };
class B { public: A a[2]; };
```

This obviously fails to compile since you're trying to use definition of the classes. And the error by the compiler would be as you're expecting

> error: field ‘b’ has incomplete type ‘B [2]’

However

```
class B;
class A { public: B* b; };
class B { public: A* a; };
```

would work just like `std::vector`. So you don't need fully defined class to use pointer or reference to this type.

Also there is simplified example with templates

```
template<typename T>
struct C {
    T* t;
};

class B;
class A { public: C<B> b; };
class B { public: C<A> a; };
```

This would also work and of course you can instantiate it

```
int main() {
    B b;
    A a;
}
```

Comment: but both vector's constructor and destructor seems no need `T` to be fully defined

Comment: is this how `vector` is supposed to work, or is it just coincidence, that it is implemented like that? I mean usually forward delcarations allow pointers to be used, but not objects and I was expecting `std::vector<B>` to fail, simply because `B` is not yet defined. Does this work in general with templates that use only pointers (i.e. something like `my_template_using_only_pointer_to_T<T>` when `T` is only forward declared) ?

Comment: @sp2danny Where have you found it? `vector` constructors use references.

Comment: According to your argument, a simple  freestanding `std::vector<B> b;` should work, too; but it doesn't. The key is that no vector object is created; we are only concerning declarations. This is akin to `typedef std::vector<B> BVec;`, which works as well. But try to add a simple `A a;` to the program, requiring code generation for the vector: it fails.

Comment: @tobi303 It is all about size of the type. So if I've understood you right, when you use pointers or references you don't need to know the exact size of the type, you simpy have 4 bytes for example to store the pointer to _any_ type. So of course this would work with any template.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev I tried it and got "...required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector()' : error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class B'"

Comment: @sp2danny What exact code and compiler do you use? Here is the example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/RxYgiq).

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev You *can*  create those vectors of B after defining B, true.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev This isn't the case. vector needs to know about the destructor and constructors of the type it holds.

Comment: @YamMarcovic of course you're right, by the time of instantiation compiler and linker need to know how to construct type. However definition of the both types can be made farther in the code since they are not needed to declare vector variable.

Comment: the DTor of the vector needs to know the full declaration of T. However, this is easy to achieve: Explicitely declare the DTors  of both `A` and `B`, and implement them in a .cpp that includes the definition of both A and B.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of template instantiation rules. At the point of `A`'s declaration, only `std::vector<B>`'s *interface* is required to be instantiated.

Since `std::vector`'s interface only uses pointers and references to its value type, and the specialization in your example gets instantiated but none of its functions are used, you don't get a compiler error for it.

As for why the compiler didn't generate `A::A()`—which would've triggered the error by calling `std::vector<B>`'s constructor—it's because your context only required its *declaration*. The compiler only needs to generate defaults for these special member functions if it sees they're used.

#### References

---

> #### § 14.7.1
>
> [...] The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members and member templates[.]
>
> #### § 12
>
> *[1]* [...] The implementation will implicitly declare these [special] member functions for some class types when the program does not explicitly declare them. *The implementation will implicitly define them if they are odr-used.*